# DocumentSnap is coming empty in firebase in php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch firestore document via php but snapshot is not showing any record

```
        $collectionReference = $this->firestore->database()->collection('orders');
        $documentReference = $collectionReference->document('Search element from document');
        $snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();
        dd($snapshot);
```

[image]

And below is my dump
[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried to use a hardcoded value like "16" for example?

Comment: yes, that was actually the issue. I was being too careless. Thank you.

Comment: Did my comment help?

Answer (score 1):

It was very stupid mistake on my end.

```
document('Search element from document');
```

to be changed with the document reference id i.e. for my case

```
document('2');
```